# How to use Material Ui on React. getting error Invalid Hook call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

`×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

I am new to React, my code was working fine but I decided to use MaterialUi today, now it's giving me errors, I have tried googling but I didn't succeed. Another thing is that my `this.state.events` is returning an Empty array, instead of a list of `events`. How do I fix this?
My React-dom version is `─ react-dom@16.13.1`   and React version is `─ react@16.13.1`

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
 import axios from "axios";

 import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
 import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
 import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";
 import GridListTileBar from "@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar";
 import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
 import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";






  export default class EventsList extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.state = { events: [] };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
     .get("http://localhost:9000/events/")
     .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ events: response.data });
    })
     .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


 render() {
   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     root: {
       display: "flex",
       flexWrap: "wrap",
       justifyContent: "space-around",
       overflow: "hidden",
       backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      },
      gridList: {
       width: 500,
       height: 450,
     },
     icon: {
      color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
     },
   }));

   const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
       <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
         <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
        </GridListTile>
        {this.state.events.map((tile) => (
          <GridListTile key={tile.img}>
            <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton
                  aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                  className={classes.icon}
                ></IconButton>
              }
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) returns a hook i.e. useStyles. You can only use hooks in functional components.

1. One option is to convert your class component to functional. Also make sure to put makeStyles code outside of component(you don't want to execute it on every re-render)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// other imports

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
  },
  icon: {
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
  },
}));

const EventsList = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9000/events/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      // rest of code...
    </div>
  );
};
```

2. Another option is to keep class based component intact and use withStyles.

See [withStyles API doc](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#arguments-5):

> Use the function signature if you need to have access to the theme. It's provided as the first argument.

```js
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
  },
  icon: {
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
  },
});

class EventsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { events: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9000/events/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
          <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
            <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
          </GridListTile>
          {this.state.events.map((tile) => (
            <GridListTile key={tile.img}>
              <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
              <GridListTileBar
                title={tile.title}
                subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
                actionIcon={
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                    className={classes.icon}
                  ></IconButton>
                }
              />
            </GridListTile>
          ))}
        </GridList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(EventsList);
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, but I noticed that terminal was showing a "compiled successfully" message, and still the browser gave me this error.

1. I actually installed the material-ui/icons as: sudo npm install -g @material-ui/icons
   ( I thought I'll install it globally as an administrator so I will not have to install material-ui, every time on different projects/react apps)
2. Inside the react app I was working, I just ran ( npm install @material-ui/icons ) which updated the node_modules folder inside my react app, and the error was gone and everything was working fine on the browser as well.
3. Solution: just run "npm install @material-ui/core" and "npm install @material-ui/icons" on the terminal, being in the react app directory your'e working in. Hopefully, everything will get fixed.

Comment: Same here, it's a very basic but we messed it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is pretty much what the error says. Hooks can be used only with functional components. `EventsList` is a class component and you are trying to use [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) in it.